# Blank quotes usage in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to combine OR `|` with `df.loc` to extract data. The code I have written extracts everything in the csv file. Here is the original csv file:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=16eo29mF0pn_qNw-BGpZyVM9PBxv2aN1G

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yelp_business.csv")
df = df.loc[(df['categories'].str.contains('chinese', case = False)) | (df['name'].str.contains('subway', case = False)) | (df['categories'].str.contains('', case = False)) | (df['address'].str.contains('', case = False))]

print df
```

It looks like the blank quotes `''` are not working in `str.contains` or the OR `|` doesn't work in `df.loc`. Instead of just returning rows with `chinese` restaurants (which are `4171` in number) and the row with the restaurant name `subway`, it returns all the `174,568` rows.

**EDITED**

The output I want should be all the rows of category `chinese` and all the rows of name `subway` while taking into consideration that the address might not have any assigned value or is null.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yelp_business.csv")

cusine = 'chinese'
name = 'subway'
address #address has no assigned value or is NULL

df = df.loc[(df['categories'].str.contains(cusine, case = False)) |
            (df['name'].str.contains(name, case = False)) | 
            (df['address'].str.contains(address, case = False))]


print df
```

This code gives me an error `NameError: name 'address' is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is possible chain conditions by `|` for `categories` column, for find empty string use `^""$` - it match start and end of string with quotes:

```
df = pd.read_csv("yelp_business.csv")

df1 = df.loc[(df['categories'].str.contains('chinese|^""$', case = False)) |
            (df['name'].str.contains('subway', case = False)) | 
            (df['address'].str.contains('^""$', case = False))]
print (len(df1))
11320
```

---

```
print (df1.head())

               business_id                     name neighborhood  \
9   TGWhGNusxyMaA4kQVBNeew  "Detailing Gone Mobile"          NaN   
53  4srfPk1s8nlm1YusyDUbjg              ***"Subway"    Southeast   
57  spDZkD6cp0JUUm6ghIWHzA              "Kitchen M"   Unionville   
63  r6Jw8oRCeumxu7Y1WRxT7A           "D&D Cleaning"          NaN   
88  YhV93k9uiMdr3FlV4FHjwA        "Caviness Studio"          NaN   

                          address       city state postal_code   latitude  \
9                           ***""  Henderson    NV       89014  36.055825   
53  "6889 S Eastern Ave, Ste 101"  Las Vegas    NV       89119  36.064652   
57            "8515 McCowan Road"    Markham    ON     L3P 5E5  43.867918   
63                          ***""     Urbana    IL       61802  40.110588   
88                          ***""    Phoenix    AZ       85001  33.449967   

     longitude  stars  review_count  is_open  \
9  -115.046350    5.0             7        1   
53 -115.118954    2.5             6        1   
57  -79.283687    3.0            80        1   
63  -88.207270    5.0             4        0   
88 -112.070223    5.0             4        1   

                                           categories  
9                           Automotive;Auto Detailing  
53                   Fast Food;Restaurants;Sandwiches  
57                             ***Restaurants;Chinese  
63         Home Cleaning;Home Services;Window Washing  
88  Marketing;Men's Clothing;Restaurants;Graphic D...
```

EDIT: If need filter out empty and NaNs values:

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['categories'].str.contains('chinese', case = False)) |
            (df['name'].str.contains('subway', case = False)) & 
           ~((df['address'] == '""') | (df['categories'] == '""'))]

print (df2.head())
                business_id              name     neighborhood  \
53   4srfPk1s8nlm1YusyDUbjg          "Subway"        Southeast   
57   spDZkD6cp0JUUm6ghIWHzA       "Kitchen M"       Unionville   
96   dTWfATVrBfKj7Vdn0qWVWg  "Flavor Cuisine"      Scarborough   
126  WUiDaFQRZ8wKYGLvmjFjAw    "China Buffet"  University City   
145  vzx1WdVivFsaN4QYrez2rw          "Subway"              NaN   

                                 address       city state postal_code  \
53         "6889 S Eastern Ave, Ste 101"  Las Vegas    NV       89119   
57                   "8515 McCowan Road"    Markham    ON     L3P 5E5   
96                "8 Glen Watford Drive"    Toronto    ON     M1S 2C1   
126  "8630 University Executive Park Dr"  Charlotte    NC       28262   
145                   "5111 Boulder Hwy"  Las Vegas    NV       89122   

      latitude   longitude  stars  review_count  is_open  \
53   36.064652 -115.118954    2.5             6        1   
57   43.867918  -79.283687    3.0            80        1   
96   43.787061  -79.276166    3.0             6        1   
126  35.306173  -80.752672    3.5            76        1   
145  36.112895 -115.062353    3.0             3        1   

                                 categories  
53         Fast Food;Restaurants;Sandwiches  
57                      Restaurants;Chinese  
96           Restaurants;Chinese;Food Court  
126  Buffets;Restaurants;Sushi Bars;Chinese  
145        Sandwiches;Restaurants;Fast Food
```

Comment: It returns all the `4171` rows for `chinese` but it is not returning any row which has the `name` `subway` in it.

Comment: @Saad - Sorry, not tested before with your real data, now it should working.

Comment: It is working fine now. Can you please tell me why `df['name'].str.contains('subway', case = False)` wasn't working before?

Comment: @Saad - Hard question, it should working. But here are combination of 3 masks, so not easy check.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much though!

Comment: hey I am sorry for coming back. but the output I am getting is not purely chinese and subway. See the very first entry you get in the output.

Comment: @Saad - There is `""` in `address` column in first row, so matched.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o8foTD90FdYr3W1qTeO8U1kMELMOYLQm this is the output I am getting. It has category `homecleaning` as well.

Comment: What I meant by `""` is an empty string or null.

Comment: @Saad - Sorry, why do you think first row cannot be matched in output from index 9?

Comment: @Saad - It working nice, because in `9` row is matched `address`, in `53` is matched `name`, in `57` is `categories`, ....

Comment: @Saad - added `***` for easy find matched rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176621/discussion-between-saad-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Saad - added another possible solution for it, but in `address` seems no missing values `print (df['address'].isnull().sum())`

Comment: It is still giving me `NameError: name 'address' is not defined` when I use the `address` **variable** in str.contains. 
The new post has **variable** in it.

Comment: need `address = '^""$'`, in question you forget assign value to variable `address`

Comment: `'^""$'` looks for cells with empty strings. The type of address I want to work with dataframe should be null or nonetype. Because of the empty string, the dataframe filters other rows which are NOT chinese or do not have a name SUBWAY.

Comment: @Saad - I think i understand now, can you check last edit?

Answer (score 0):

Find detail information about ***contains*** at
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: I have read it. I still can't devise a solution for my problem.

Comment: We will find fundamental knowledge of contains method, Hope this will help you to understand basics. Thanks